# How to login on On-premises sharepoint(local sharepoint) in IOS?

Tags: ios, sharepoint

Trying to make an app for local sharepoint login and access sharepoint list data in IOS app. I have try to login and pass parameter as username and password but give error **401 unauthorized**.
I tried to login. Only one response send **401 unauthorized** by server.
Please help me.

Comment: Check this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/10/06/developing-ios-apps-with-azure-and-office-365-apis/

Comment: @AndreyVolobuev thanks for replay it used for online sharepoint only.Its not works on On-Premises.